# Dealing with Discrete numeric variables in logistic regression model

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, discrete-data

i have one relevant variable in my model like number of additional services taken by customer
with visual inspection it is clear more the number of additional services customer opts in lesser the chances of customer to leave. i m creating logistic regression model for predicting customer's propensity to leave. How shall i treat this variable?
as numeric or treat it as  categorical variables and create dummy variable for it.
(As of now range of number of additional services is between 0 to 10)..
please suggest.

Comment: While not foolproof I often get satisfactory fits by using a quadratic effect of a count variable that is a predictor.

Answer (score 0):

Are you only interested in the effect of the number of services? Then use a single count variable. Use dummies for every service (or group of services) if you want to distinguish between the effects of the different services offered.

Comment: i am interested in number of services.. so are you suggesting to treat it as discrete numeric data and should not convert it into dummies?

Comment: In that case discrete numeric is ok